# ConcurrencyException on HttpPost asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello  I am trying to edit my table in db and is give me this error **An update, insert, or delete instruction in the store has affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since loading.**

> trying many test and when i'm arrive on SaveChange  is stop process
>   and incomplete operaion
>
> This is the implementation

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            db = new IdentityDBEntities();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
            if (article == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Idc = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle", article.Idc);

            return View(article);
        }

        // POST: Articles/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,UserId,Idc,titre,image")] Article article, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    article.image = image.FileName;
                }
                db = new IdentityDBEntities();
                article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges(); 


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Idc = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle", article.Idc);

            return View(article);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Article was loaded in one instance of a DbContext, and you are attempting to save it with another instance. The entity would need to be associated to the new context before being saved. (I.e. `Attach` or `Update`) However, I do not recommend this approach.

As a general rule you should avoid passing entities to and from a web client. If you accept an entity to a web client, it is a simple matter to find the call passing the modified entity to the server, apply a breakpoint, and modify the contents using the debugger before resuming. If the server merely attaches the entity to a context and saves the changes, I can modify data in ways the application should not allow. It also involves sending more information to/from the client than is typically necessary.

You also run into the problem that the data supporting an entity loaded at one point in your current session has been modified by another session between the time you read the data, and the time you're prepared to update it. Systems should not merely attach and overwrite data without first verifying (via something like a Timestamp or last modified date/time) that the data hasn't been updated since the entity was loaded. From there the system can take an appropriate action. (log that data will be overwritten, overwrite, or merge & notify the user to review their changes.)

edit: To outline an example.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,UserId,Idc,titre,image")] Article article, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Idc = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle", article.Idc);
        return View(article); 
    }

    using (var db = new IdentityDBEntities())
    {
        var existingArticle = db.Articles.Single(x => x.ArticleId == article.ArticleId);
        if (existingArticle.RowVersion != article.RowVersion) // Or compare LastModifiedDateTime etc.
        {
            // Set a validation state to tell the user that the article had changed since they started editing. Perhaps merge values across, but send the article back.
            return View(existingArticle);
        }

        if (image != null)
            existingArticle.image = image.FileName;

        existingArticle.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); // can this be updated?
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The key differences:
DbContext's are disposable so should be wrapped in a `using` block.
We load the article from the context, check if it's been modified since we had originally loaded it. (other validation checks to ensure the user can modify this article would be prudent as well) if it isn't out of date and is valid, transfer the fields across and save the changes.

Comment: I've updated the answer to outline an example to reload the entity and transpose the values after checking that the updated object wasn't stale, plus indicate where other validation should occur.

Comment: Thanks brother is working for me before i see your post my code is corred problem is like you said is on entity framework  Thanks steve is useful